# Are adjustable monitor stands safe to pack in checked luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, safety

I have a monitor and stand (HP ZR2240w) that I would like to take with me as part of an international move.

The monitor stand is fairly heavy, and contains some kind of spring - it's not clear whether it's a compressed gas spring or a simple metal coil. I can't get a look inside the mechanism, the plastic shell seems fairly stubborn to remove to expose the internals.

If there is a gas spring inside, will this be safe under the reduced air pressure?

Are consumer products in the US required to have labels indicating the presence of compressed gas inside?

Comment: Have you asked HP about the stand's construction?

Comment: Quoth the tech support channel, _"Vishnu: 
The monitor has metal spring in the stand and does not contain compressed gas cylinder."_ (case id 5037902130)

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Containers of compressed gas do not explode when an aircraft reaches cruising altitude. They might, however, explode if the aircraft has a rapid depressurization at cruising altitude.

Comment: @MichaelHampton There has been cases of that. Even canned food, like surströmming, has popped in hold luggage with eeh kind of severe consequences. The most important problem is perhaps that unexplainable noises and bangs from the hold may be enough for the crew to opt for a diversion or emergency landing.

Comment: @Eric It's OK to answer your own question by completing the "Your Answer" box below and posting the info, so that others reading your question will know there is a substantive response.

Answer (score 3):

From HP's support response, as commented by the OP:

"Vishnu: The monitor has metal spring in the stand and does not contain compressed gas cylinder." (case id 5037902130)

so it should be fine to travel on the plane.

Comment: I've taken a few to bits recently, and they all use a rather neat coiled metal spring, rather like a slap band.  This is much cheaper than a gas spring would be, and bring some friction with it for free